# Youtube video not playing on iPhones

Tags: iphone, youtube

http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/videos-test

I am using the YouTube iframe code below, but on my iPhone I only get the black box with the YouTube logo, and clicking it does nothing.

Removing `?rel=0;autoplay=1` doesn't help.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RwqfR8g-Qow?rel=0;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: have you tried to use the youtube.com?watch=id.. url instead of youtube embede/..

Comment: You mean like `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com?watch=RwqfR8g-Qow" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`? I wanted to use the code from Youtube, as my clients will have to embed videos themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try use iframe with a playlist:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/p/PLAYLIST_ID"
```

I heard there is a reference on youtube developer forum on how to do this..

Comment: glad to know :) if this answer helps help me to vote if u dun mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Select 'Use old embed code' in the YouTube options, which outputs:

```
<object width="640" height="360"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/RwqfR8g-Qow?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/RwqfR8g-Qow?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Didn't realise this was all it would take, sorry guys! I assumed that the default code in YouTube would be iPhone friendly. Silly me.